# wp_login Action hook with conditional tag

Tags: hooks, conditional-tags

i tried to create a simple function to receive a email when a specify user is logged, i tried with $current_user->ID and also with wp_get_current_user() but not working. This is my code:

```
function InvioMail() {
     global $current_user;
   $ID = $current_user->ID;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
  $name = $user->user_login;

    if ($name == 'piero') {

        $to = 'example@mail.com';
        $subject = 'test su action hook wp_login';
        $body = 'test su action hook pwp_login';
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: My Site Name <support@example.com');

        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_login', 'InvioMail');
```

Without if condition work property but when i try with IF nothing.

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you, make sure that the `user_login` or `user_id` matches to the string you're using in the condition. Try to do a `var_dump($user_login);`

And about the function you're using, you don't need to grab the `global` or call `get_current_user();`, because the action you're calling already pass two parameters to your function, the first is a `string` with the `$user_login`, and the second is a `WP_User object` the current logged in user.

To use it, just change your code to this:

```
function InvioMail($user_login, $user) {

  if ($user_login == 'piero') {

    $to = 'example@mail.com';
    $subject = 'test su action hook wp_login';
    $body = 'test su action hook pwp_login';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: My Site Name <support@example.com');

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_login', 'InvioMail', 10, 2);
```

To learn more about this hook, check the [Docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login).

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :)... could you pelase mark that as the correct answer, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.

```
function InvioMail() {
  global $current_user;

  if ($current_user->ID == 1){ // change id 1 to your user id 

    $to = 'example@mail.com';
    $subject = 'test su action hook wp_login';
    $body = 'test su action hook pwp_login';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: My 
    Site Name <support@example.com');

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
   }
}

add_action( 'wp_login', 'InvioMail');
```

Comment: i tried... not work:(